# pyodbc SQL Server Driver Error [unixODBC][Driver Manager] Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.1.1’

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pyodbc

I have been unable to connect to SQL Server using pyodbc

```py
pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={host};DATABASE={db};UID={user};PWD={pwd};TrustServerCertificate=yes;')
```

Getting an error: Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.1.1’

**I am however able to run this command and it connects fine:**

```bash
isql -v -k “DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={host};DATABASE={db};UID={user};PWD={pwd};TrustServerCertificate=yes;”
```

I have tried every suggestion. Even added the sql server driver path to my LD_LIBRARY environment variable.

Here is what I get after running: odbcinst -q -d

```
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
```

odbcinst -j

```
$ odbcinst -j unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS. . . .......: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES /etc/ODBCDataSources
SQLULEN Size........:8
SQLLEN Size.........:8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

This is the content of odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.1.1
UsageCount=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.6.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

Running RHEL 8, python 3.9.10 and pyodbc==4.0.39

**More details**

```py
import pyodbc

pyodbc.drivers()
# ['ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']

pyodbc.dataSources()
#{}
```

Comment: not sure it matters but why are you quotes not written correctly? Is that your code, or is it SO rendering?

Comment: @topsail the notes application messed up my quotes. I copied the code into a word processor and it messed up my quotes. I have fixed it already. Thanks

Comment: Are you running your Python code in a virtual environment like Anaconda?

Comment: If you `ls -la /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.1.1` do you see exactly `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2096192 Jul  4 16:18 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.1.1`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, I see exactly that, except for the date of course

Comment: @GordThompson good question. My python code is not running in Anaconda. However, python is not necessarily installed in the linux os where they code is running.  There is a central repository from where python 3.9.10 module is loaded at the time the script runs. Libraries, like pyodbc, sqlalchemy, pymongo, etc. are installed in the system and added to PYTHONPATH before running the code.

Comment: The date is when the library was built by Microsoft... yours is different?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning date is Jul 4 19:18. Actually, it's seems like the same but we are on different time zones :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the comments on the OP question, in which it's mentioned that the python module is loaded and not necessarily installed on your system, this could be related to version of the gcc that was used to compile the python binaries not being compatible with the version used to compile the unixODBC binaries. I had a similar issue once.

- So I ended up installing python directly on the system. That resolved the issue for me.
- If that is not possible, try to load a different version of python from the module repository. That version of python might have been compiled with a different version of the gcc.

Comment: Wow, this worked. Thanks. TBH, I didn't have much faith in this solution but I asked our admin to install python3 directly in the system just to discard the possibility. To my surprise, it worked great. Thanks again.